# Getting the App to execute background code when receiving a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, notifications

I am using iOS 8 and I am scheduling a UILocalNotification as **work-around** to the fact that I **cannot execute background code** unless for a finite amount of time or that the app belongs to certain categories (E.g. communicates with external BLE accessories, etc.. but even so it would be limited to that code):

[Background execution documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)):

> If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a little extra time
>   to complete that task, it can call the
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication
>   object to request some additional execution time.

**What I want to achieve is to check if there are some conditions that are met at the time in which the UILocalNotification is fired** (using local notification seems the only way to get the app to execute something whilst in background..). **Unless there is another way..**

Unfortunately I seem to be able to intercept the call and execute code only when the app enters the foreground (users tap the notification badge and the ** didReceiveLocalNotification** gets called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
```

This corresponds to the behaviour described by [Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26).

> The user taps the default button in the alert or taps (or clicks) the
>   app icon. If the default action button is tapped (on a device running
>   iOS), the system launches the app and the app calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, passing in the
>   notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications). Although
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn’t the best place to
>   handle the notification, getting the payload at this point gives you
>   the opportunity to start the update process before your handler method
>   is called.

**Any idea on how I can intercept the UILocalNotification whilst the app is in background and execute some code without having the user to tap on the notification?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the firing of a local notification in itself to launch your app in the background. As you have noted, your app only executes if the user taps the notification.

You can use a remote notification with a content-available key to launch your application in the background.

Comment: Has anything changed since 2013?